# Send mixpanel cookies with server side logging?

Tags: python, analytics, server-side, mixpanel

Have you found a way to pass mixpanel user cookies through on server side logging events?

I tried passing them as args to server-side mixpanel.track, but that didn't work, e.g.

```
from mixpanel import Mixpanel
def log_mixpanel(userid,request=None,event=None,args=None):
    if args == None:
        args = {}
    if userid and event:
        if request:
            for cookie in request.COOKIES:
                if cookie.startswith("mp_"):
                    args[cookie]=request.COOKIES[cookie]
        mp = Mixpanel(settings.MIXPANEL_PROJECT_TOKEN)
        mp.track(userid,event,args)
```

I could try hacking the mixpanel python library to copy request headers over, but I'm wondering if there's a friendlier way.

I'm hoping to populate as many of the same fields as possible to match the javascript library's logging, including Device. This requires copying useragent & other request headers over to mixpanel somehow as well.